# Are there more ways to highlight comments in PHPstorm than TODO or FIXME?

Tags: phpstorm, highlighting

I knew already about the **TODO:** comment highlighting and just now saw that there is also a **FIXME:** highlighting.

I work in PHPStorm most of the time and want to know if there are other highlist-keywords.

TODO: & FIXME: both become the same color (blue).
My main question is if there are more keywords like this that have different colors?

Thanks for explanation and sorry if this question is not relevant enough..

Comment: In Edit>Color&Fonts you have all colors for this :)

Comment: You can also define new ones in PHPStorm

Comment: @Christian > Don't see that option in PHPSTorm7.0

Comment: @Samuel > Do you, by any chance, know how and where?

Comment: @MarcelvanderHorst, No, but appearently JetBrains does :D http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+todo+comments+and+the+todo+tool+window

Comment: @MarcelvanderHorst sorry try it in File>Prefereces>Editor>Color&Fonts

Comment: @Christian > Thanks, this will do good for now..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible using custom TODO patterns

- add you own TODO pattern in "Settings | TODO", define the desired color and font (uncheck 'Use color scheme TODO default colors', set the preferred colors
- Then on TODO tool window you can filter what todos to show (if you don't like your comments to appear in TODO tool window)

See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+todo+comments+and+the+todo+tool+window